# Como apagar todos os arquivos untracked de uma vez no git?

Tags: git

Rodando `git status` em uma pasta:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   b.txt

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   a.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        c.txt
        d.txt
        e.txt
```

Qual a melhor forma de apagar os arquivos `c.txt`, `d.txt` e `e.txt` dessa pasta sem mexer nos arquivos `a.txt` e `b.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o comando `git clean -f`.

Caso você queira verificar quais arquivos seriam deletados antes de executar a exclusão, você pode usar a opção `-n`, exemplo:

```
git clean -n
```

A saída seria:

```
Would remove c.txt
Would remove d.txt
Would remove e.txt
```

Ao executar o comando `git clean -f`, a saída é:

```
Removing c.txt
Removing d.txt
Removing e.txt
```

[Documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean)

Answer (score 2):

Quando eu quero voltar com o repositório ao mesmo estado após um clone, por exemplo, não basta não ter nenhum arquivo a ser "commitado", já que é possível ter arquivos que estão sendo ignorados pelo .gitignore.

Durante o processo de desenvolvimento, ao rodarmos a aplicação para debugarmos, o compilador criar arquivos intermediários, para linkar o código, ou o próprio arquivo EXE ou uma dll, ou qualquer outro resultado de compilação.

```
git clean -fxd
```

- f ou --force, para forçar a remoção dos arquivos
- x, para remover arquivos ignorados, essa opção é interessante, pois remove arquivos criados em um build, por exemplo, (obj, exe, ...)
- d, remove em todos os diretórios